# PGFplots xaxis to use exact values and not scale

Tags: pgfplots

I have a graph with values in xaxis as powers of 2. PGFplots automatically changes the x labels. I want it to use the exact values. What option should I use?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
1   1
2   3
4   5
8   7
16  7
32  7
64  8
128 9
}\datafile
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        title=test
        ,xlabel=size
        ,ylabel=Througput
    ]
    \addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add `xtick=data` then only the data points are taken as tick values. And you get

[image]

Instead you can use the loagrithmic axis for `x` values and change the base of logarithm to 2 via adding `log basis x` key.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotstableread
{
thread  speedup
1   1
2   3
4   5
8   7
16  7
32  7
64  8
128 9
}\datafile

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
        title=test
        ,xlabel=size
        ,ylabel=Througput,xtick=data,log basis x=2
    ]
    \addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup,color=red,mark=x] {\datafile};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried both the versions. Version 1 has all the x ticks but it automatically scales the xaxis. In version 2 as log axis is used, scaling is even, but the numbers are displayed in  powers of 2. So I modified version 1 to include `symbolic x coords={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128}` so that it doesn't scale the axis